# Help with a conditional probability problem

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

There are 6 balls in a bag and they are numbered 1 to 6.
We draw two balls without replacement.
Is the probability of drawing a "6" followed by drawing an "even" ball the same as the probability of drawing an "even" ball followed by drawing a "6".

According to Bayes Theorem these two possibilities should be the same:

Pr(A and B) = Pr(A) x Pr(B∣A)
Pr(A and B) = Pr(B) x Pr(A∣B)

However, when I try to work this out I am getting two different probabilities, 2/30 and 3/30 for the two different scenarios listed above. The first scenario is fairly straight-forward to determine,

Pr(6) x Pr(even∣6 has already been drawn)
1/6 x 2/5 = 2/30

however, I think I am doing something wrong with the second scenario,

Pr(even) x Pr(6∣even has already been drawn)
3/6 x ?????

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is really bugging me.
Thank you in advance....

Comment: The $\tfrac 3 6$ is wrong. Also, the formatting of your post is ... atrocious.

Comment: Wow...thank you so much for your post. It was most helpful, you have pointed out that I am doing something wrong with determining the probability of the second scenario, which is what I stated in my question and which is why I was asking for help. This is the first time I have posted to this forum and I have to say I certainly wasn't expecting such a rude and pointless reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, replace the "even" condition with the new condition "2 or 4."  Since you can't draw 6 twice in a row, this is an equivalent problem.

Given this, it should be straightforward to see that (2 or 4)-then-(6) has odds $(\frac{2}{6})(\frac{1}{5}) = \frac{1}{15}$, and that (6)-then-(2 or 4) has odds $(\frac{1}{6})(\frac{2}{5}) = \frac{1}{15}$.  Let me know if that needs clarification.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I was also able to solve it using a probability tree.  Cheers, Shelster.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to compute anything. All orders of drawing the balls are equally likely.